# Samba share not accessible by IP address, is by hostname

Tags: ubuntu, samba

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 box with PBIS and Samba. Samba shares are accessible when using the hostname from Windows machines but not by IP address. The message when using IP address to navigate to share says the username or password is incorrect. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that the hostname.domain resolves to the same IP you are referring to? Maybe your Samba listens on the different IP address? Why would you use Samba if you have PBIS, why not using shares from PBIS/AD directly?

Comment: Yes, it resolves to the correct IP address. I don't think I understand your second question. Thank you

Comment: Then we will need at least some information from the logs on your linux server during the time when you get "login failed" error on windows machine.

Have you tried to access Samba shares from the linux machine?

My second question referred to the following:
[Configure_Samba_to_Bind_to_Specific_Interfaces](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Configure_Samba_to_Bind_to_Specific_Interfaces)

Comment: Thanks, no it isn't specified to bind to a specific interface. What log(s) would be most helpful? In the Syslog it displays: lsass: [lsass] Failed to authenticate user (name = 'npales) -> error = 40121, symbol = LW_ERROR_DOMAIN_IS_OFFLINE, client pid = 2815. Thank you

Comment: In looking at this it looks like it isn't passing the domain on the username when I attempt to access it via IP address, but is when using the hostname.

Comment: Are you trying to get those shares with linux local users? Or you are trying to access it from with AD username/password? it's more related to pbis, as when you try to authentificate using the hostname, it's adding your domain name to it, which resolves to the IP but also it searches for SRV records, that brings your query to the AD, it does authentication and you are able to login.

I am 90% positive that if you would enter linux username and password it will work.

Comment: I am attempting to access with AD username and password, yes. Yes with a local linux user I am able to access the shares. Just not sure why it's adding the domain name when accessing with hostname and not IP address?

Comment: That is how the system designed, when you type in any hostname, it automatically searches for the domain record in the DNS records of your AD tree. With the IP address system cannot add any DNS prefix to it. That is why it works with linux users and not with AD users when you use IP. How your linux server would know for which domain you are logging in? If you are not specifiying the hostname, then you will need to specify username+domainname in the username field, that will trigger AD authentification versus linux PAM. Hope this helps

Comment: I think in windows you can specify login like this ```yourdomain.com\username```

Comment: Right. But I am supplying the domain name when accessing the share, but it doesn't seem to be passing it.

Comment: how do you passing it exactly? Can you provide a screenshot from windows and the syslog records during the time of authentication?

Comment: I actually just gave up and reloaded the box as it wasn't in production yet. It is all working now as it should. I believe it was an issue where the nameservers I specified weren't actually being applied. All good now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -2):

Reloaded machine, now working...